# Is there any reason to have the "Scheduled Approval" timer job run every minute?

Tags: publishing, timer-jobs

Why is the Scheduled Approval timer job in SharePoint 2010 scheduled to run every minute by default?  What are the potential issues with making it 5 or 10 minutes?  Does this timer job only apply to pages or does it also apply to other types of content?

Answer (score 2):

Moreover, each timer job has its own default schedule for when the job runs. You can change the frequency with which each job runs on the Job Definitions page on the Central Administration Web site. It entirely depends upon how often content editors engage with the SharePoint portal for creating content, number of users within the organization and so on. There is no special reason for timer job to run every one minute but it may affect other time jobs if you change default time

Comment: I guess that's my real question -- If I change this particular timer job to run every 10 minutes, would I also need to change other timer jobs?  Would this change cause errors?

Comment: As per Microsoft best pratices there shouldn't be an issue except few that are mentioned in the article : http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc678870.aspx#ManageJobs. The very notion of timer job is to execute a routine after repeated period of time. Hope it helps